# Split a shapefile into multiple shapefiles based on a particular Field

Tags: python, shapefile, splitting

I have a shapefile where there are 3 fields OBJECTID, NAME , LOCALITY. I want to create new shapefile that contains the geometry, projection etc. of the parent shapefile and according to the locality;

```
OBJECTID    NAME    LOCALITY
1    JOHN    UK
2    ANITA   USA
3    CAL     USA
4    DAVE    UK

This shapefile is read and two seperate shape files are created with the properties
of the parent shape files

OBJECTID    NAME    LOCALITY
1    JOHN    UK
2    DAVE    UK
OBJECTID    NAME    LOCALITY
1    ANITA   USA
2    CAL     USA
```

Please guide me how to do it. I am new to Python

Comment: What software do you have available? This question is a possible duplicate [http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22584/making-multiple-separate-selections-from-attributes/22585#22585](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22584/making-multiple-separate-selections-from-attributes/22585#22585)

Comment: Much more about this FAQ is available by searching our site: http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=split+shapefile+attribute+arcgis

Comment: Another post that will help you is here: [How can i split by attribute in ArcGIS 10?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44410/how-can-i-split-by-attribute-in-arcgis-10) - a couple of the answers either have Python code or you can open up the script tools that are mentioned to examine the code and modify for your purposes.

Comment: Very late to the game but this isnt a duplicate. This question is about using python and makes no mention of arcgis.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a tutorial showing you how to do exactly what you're looking for.  Before you start you'll need to install the gdal/ogr bindings for Python.  Information for that can be found here:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/

Here's a question from here on how to install the bindings:

[Installing GDAL and OGR for Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9553/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-gdal-and-ogr-for-python)

And here's the tutorial:

http://cosmicproject.org/OGR/cris_example_write.html

Comment: Late to the game but this answer highlights the issue with link only answers. The link is dead and now the answer is too

Comment: the link does not work anymore

Comment: Here's the archived link: https://web.archive.org/web/20110719165550/http://cosmicproject.org/OGR/cris_example_write.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have ArcGIS at your disposal and do not want to write anything from scratch, there is already a [tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=37AEB018-1422-2418-A036-CA6D9920F808) available for that (if I got you right, you want to "split" the shapefile by a certain attribute).

You could also build a model:

[image]

Or check another GIS Stackexchange [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44410/how-can-i-split-by-attribute-in-arcgis-10).